# Canvas progress wheel

Tags: canvas

I'm trying to make a progress wheel that matches a mockup given

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k2Hh.jpg

Progress so far...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMsGL.jpg

I got close with another dev, and some googlin, but not sure about how to complete the mockup. Mainly by completing the circle in a smaller circle and basing the % of the circle on outside variables.

The idea is that I'll do some math based on a multiple of 6. So if the user is 1/6 then the graph is 16.6 complete. 3/6 50% and so on. Need to know where I can input that.

```js
var counter = document.getElementById('counter').getContext('2d');
var no = 50; // Starting Point
var pointToFill = 4.72; //Point from where you want to fill the circle
var cw = counter.canvas.width; //Return canvas width
var ch = counter.canvas.height; //Return canvas height
var diff; // find the different between current value (no) and trageted value (100)

function fillCounter() {
  diff = ((no / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10);
  counter.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch); // Clear canvas every time when function is call
  counter.lineWidth = 15; // size of stroke

  counter.fillStyle = '#000'; // color that you want to fill in counter/circle
  counter.strokeStyle = '#489DA0'; // Stroke Color
  counter.textAlign = 'center';
  counter.font = "25px monospace"; //set font size and face
  counter.lineCap = "round";
  counter.fillText(no + '%', 100, 110); //fillText(text,x,y);
  counter.beginPath();
  counter.arc(100, 100, 90, pointToFill, diff / 10 + pointToFill); //arc(x,y,radius,start,stop)

  counter.stroke(); // to fill stroke

  // now add condition

  if (no >= 80) {
    clearTimeout(fill); //fill is a variable that call the function fillcounter()}
    no++;
  }
}

//now call the function
var fill = setInterval(fillCounter, 100); //call the fillCounter function after every 50MS
```

```html
<canvas height="200" width="200" id="counter">
```

Comment: Thanks. Have any idea to make a smaller circle all the way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got really close all you needed was the smaller line circle.

Here is how you do it:

```js
var counter = document.getElementById('counter').getContext('2d');
var no = 50; // Starting Point
var pointToFill = 4.72; //Point from where you want to fill the circle
var cw = counter.canvas.width; //Return canvas width
var ch = counter.canvas.height; //Return canvas height
var diff; // find the different between current value (no) and trageted value (100)

function fillCounter() {
  diff = ((no / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10);
  counter.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch); // Clear canvas every time when function is call

  counter.fillStyle = '#000'; // color that you want to fill in counter/circle
  counter.strokeStyle = '#489DA0'; // Stroke Color
  counter.textAlign = 'center';
  counter.font = "25px monospace"; //set font size and face
  counter.lineCap = "round";
  counter.fillText(no + '%', 100, 110); //fillText(text,x,y);

  counter.beginPath();
  counter.lineWidth = 2;
  counter.arc(100, 100, 90, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  counter.stroke();

  counter.beginPath();
  counter.lineWidth = 15; // size of stroke
  counter.arc(100, 100, 90, pointToFill, diff / 10 + pointToFill);
  counter.stroke();
}


fillCounter()
```

```html
<canvas height="200" width="200" id="counter">
```

Now we have 2 arcs one is a full circle (`lineWidth = 2`)
and the second is a partial with (`lineWidth = 15`)